# How to simplify angular model change in a form

Tags: angularjs

I have a form containing 10 textbox (firstname, country, lastname, ages,...)
I bind my form with  employee object
I want to to display a Save button only when the user modify any of these fields.
I use  ng-if with a bool variable btnVisible for the Button. Then ng-change for each textbox. I find this too much

Queston: is there another simplest way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use $dirty. 
Here's a [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) on how that works. 
And here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/unmskyc5/) I found.

you have to add a form, something like:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
```

Comment: can we call  myform.$dirty in the javascript? Because the user type employee 1 in emploee Id box. I call my sevice to bring the employee information and bien to the MyForm. Now i want to know when user change any field

Comment: Yes you can. You can access the form by using $scope.myForm.$dirty